# Is there a way to detect if the user clicks on the right or left side of the trackpad?

Tags: objective-c, tvos

Given that touches always start at 0,0 I can't find a simple way to detect where exactly on the trackpad the touch originated.

Comment: Also, UIPressTypeRightArrow gets me close, but I want it to be on click instead of tap.

Answer (score 5):

Detecting the location of an actual click might not be as easy as it seems, or even possible. It's important here to distinguish between a click and a tap. Taps are intended for selecting information, and clicks for confirmation, as described in the Apple Human Interface Guidelines. For that reason, Apple did not include an easy way to distinguish between locations of clicks, while such exist for taps. Following from this, my first suggestion would be to rethink the interface, and use taps and clicks as intended. I do recognize though that in a lot of cases, that's not possible.

The new remote has a touch surface with a physical button under it.

Physical button clicks and taps are represented by the `UIPress` classes and recognized by gesture recongizers when you set the `allowedPressTypes`. The press type for a physical button click is `UIPressTypeSelect`.

Since `UIPressTypeSelect` does not distinguish the location on the actual trackpad, and the event it creates returns the location in `UIWindow` on the actual screen, a combination of events would be necessary here to complete the task.

Use the method below to detect when the presses began. Then look for a `UIPress` of the type

```
UIPressTypeUpArrow
UIPressTypeDownArrow
UIPressTypeLeftArrow
UIPressTypeRightArrow
```

This will indicate a touch. This should be followed by another `UIPress` event of type `UIPressTypeSelect`. This will indicate the user clicked the location they initially touched.

```
- (void)pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {  
    for (UIPress *item in presses) {
    }
}
```

This is not a perfect solution, and it might be worth filing a bug report with Apple and requesting the feature.

Another option for getting more fine control over the remote would be using `GCController`, but that might complicate things, and it looks like it's outside of the scope of this question.